# Counting how many words of a list are used in a string

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

I have a list that looks like this one below:

```
$hotWords = ['fedora', 'tips', 'reddit', '/r/', 'god', 'le', 'army', 'iq', 'redditor', 'm\'lady'];
```

The idea is that the more these words appear in a string, the higher the "weighting" becomes.

I was planning to use some case insensitive regex to match these phrases, however I want an extra point added for every word use, which includes adding a weight value every time the word appears, even if it is repeated.

Essentially just every match in this array equals one extra point. How can I go about programming this?

Comment: maybe use preg_replace() with some unique and than substr_count() that unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like: `/\b(word1|word2|word3|word4)\b/is` in a `preg_match_all` call, to get the total number of occurences:

```
$hotWords = ['fedora', 'tips', 'reddit', '/r/', 'god', 'le', 'army', 'iq', 'redditor', 'm\'lady'];
$re = '/\b(' . implode('|', array_map(function($word) { return preg_quote($word, '/'); }, $hotWords)) . ')\b/is';
$string = 'fedora foo bar tips fedora fedoras';
//         ^1             ^2   ^3
echo preg_match_all($re, $string); // 3
```

Note, however, this won't match "words" starting or ending with word delimiters like `/r/`, so you might want to replace the `\b`'s with your own set of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hotWords = ['fedora', 'tips', 'reddit', '/r/', 'god', 'le', 'army', 'iq', 'redditor', 'm\'lady'];
$points = substr_count(
    preg_replace('#('.implode('|',$hotWords).')#','**~'~**',$string)
,'**~'~**');
```

maybe.. can done better, maybe you have too extra escape some chars for the regex

Comment: and keep in mind that e.g. 'tip' and 'tipper' not working here, only unique lookups

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the string into an array of words and run [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) on the arrays to get the matching words. This will work for `/r/` and other regexp-unfriendly "words" as well.

```
// Define hot words and string
$hotWords = ['fedora', 'tips', 'reddit', '/r/', 'god',
             'le', 'army', 'iq', 'redditor', 'm\'lady'];
$str = 'foo reddit   tips bar reddit /r/i/p/ /r/ baz';

// Turn string into array and get intersection (matches)
$words   = preg_split('/\s+/', $str); // \s+ allows for multiple spaces
$matches = array_intersect($words, $hotWords);

// Echo count
echo count($matches), PHP_EOL; // reddit + tips + reddit + /r/ => 4
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: This won't match things like `fedoras` when using the hotword `fedora` though.

Comment: For that you will either have to add those variants to the `$hotWords` array or use a more complex matching algorithm. You may want to have a look at [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) and [metaphone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php).